# php using pdo simple login system issues

Tags: php, mysql, session, pdo, authentication

```
 <?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
require 'Config.php';

    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    try {
      $Name = $_POST['Name'];
      $Password = $_POST['Password'];
      $message ="";

      $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE Name='$Name' and Password='$Password'");
      $stmt->execute();
      $result = $stmt->fetchcolumn();

         if($result > 0)
         {
           $_SESSION['Logged In'] = $Name;
           $_SESSION['Logged In'] = $Password;
           if(isset($_SESSION['Logged In']))
             {
                 echo $result;
                 session_start();
                 header('Location: Main.php');
                 exit();
             }
         }
         elseif($result == 0)
         {
             echo $result;
             echo "Invalid Username or Password";
         }
    }
   catch(PDOException $e)
   {
    echo $e->getMessage();
   }
   $conn = null;
  }
?>
```

i need help with this simple login system if i comment out the header redirect the echo result shows i am only getting 1 result as expected when i put the redirect in the page just refreshes instead of going to the next page.

Comment: It's so simple it's unsave

Comment: sorry i am quite new to this don't get what you mean

Comment: Please don't write session key with spaces like `$_SESSION['Logged In']` also make sure the path you give to header is absolute, not relative..

Comment: a) *every time you store an unhashed password, root moves a kitten to /dev/null* - use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` b), use parameterized statements, you are vulnerable to **SQL-Injections**

Comment: Your logic is completely Wrong, this is not how you should do a login script, and why are your passwords stored in plain text?

Comment: Yes, I took a second look and this code as many issue, you should never put a variable directly inside prepare(), never put a variable ... or your database will be hacked ... and very easily

Comment: this is a simple uni project not going live on the internet so security is not a top priority

Comment: It doesn't matter if its only a uni project. You should learn it the right way if you do. And the way you wrote your query, your DB can be hacked ina few seconds. Look at http://bobby-tables.com for more information about SQL injection and how to prevent them.

Comment: @Tom632 *this is a simple uni project not going live on the internet so security is not a top priority*  That's absolute nonsense, even if you working on your local host, if you keep on using things the wrong way how are you gonna learn?

Comment: $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Count(*) FROM user WHERE Name=:Name and Password=:Password");
 $stmt ->bindParam(':Name',$Name);
    $stmt ->bindParam(':Password', $Password); 
    $stmt->execute();

Comment: thats the way i did it before the header is the problem i am having ]

Comment: @Tom632 **Because its a Uni Project** You should be demonstrating best practice and not learning bad habits. If it is going to be marked, it should be marked down for bad security. There is enough bad code out there already we dont need it adding to

Answer (score 1):

There are a few simple issues in this code

First you must start the session before you do anything with it. In fact its best to start it at the top of every script before doing anything else.

Also because you have echoed something to the browser before you have run the header, this will be a probelm. Headers have to be sent before any page data.

Also your code is liable to SQL Injection so use prepared and parameterised queries to avoid this.

You also appear to be storing a plain text password in the database. another big No No

> PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
>   and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
>   And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)
>   If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

    require 'Config.php';

    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    try {

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Password 
                                FROM user 
                                WHERE Name=:name");

        $params = array(':name'=>$_POST['Name'])
        $stmt->execute($params);
        $hashedPassword = $stmt->fetchcolumn();

        if(password_verify($_POST['Password'], $hashedPassword) ) {
            $_SESSION['Logged In'] = $_POST['Name'];

            // bad idea putting password in a session
            //$_SESSION['Logged In'] = $Password;

            // you just set this data so the if is unnecessary
            //if(isset($_SESSION['Logged In'])) {

            // cannot echo anything before doing a header()
            // any way if the header works you wont see this data 
            // anyway as a new page will be being loaded
            //echo $result;
            header('Location: Main.php');
            exit;
         } else {
            echo $result;
            echo "Invalid Username or Password";
     }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    $conn = null;
}
?>
```

As this now uses a hashed password, you will have to recreate your users and when tou do, use

```
$passwordToPutOnDatabase = password_hash($thepassword);
```

Comment: @Tom632 A thanks normally comes in the form of an upvote if you think that any question helps you. Upvotes cost you nothing

Answer (score 0):

There are may issues with your code, you are storing passwords in plain text which is completely wrong, you should use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`

I have made you a simple login/register script which will show you how to use the password_hash and password_verify()

**simple_register.php**

```
<?php

    require 'db_config.php';
    if(isset($_POST['register'])){

        //validate email and password I'm not gonna do that for you



        $password = $_POST['upass']; // when u done with validation
        $email = $_POST['username'];



        $hash = password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT); //hash password

        try {

                $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username,password) VALUES ( ?,?)");
                if($stmt->execute(array($email,$hash))){

                    echo "user registered";
                }else{

                    echo "could not register"; // something wrong with your query check error log
                }

        } catch (Exception $e) {

            error_log($e->getMessage());

        }

    }

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple PDO Registration</title>
</head>
<body>


<form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">


    <p><input type="email" name="username" placeholder="Enter your email"></p>
    <p><input type="password" name="upass" placeholder="Enter password"></p>

    <button type="submit" name="register">Register</button>



</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    require 'db_config.php';

if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {

    header("location:users/dashboard.php");
} else {


    $loginMessage = "";
    $msg_class    = "";

    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {


        if (empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['upass'])) {

            $loginMessage = "Enter username and password";
            $msg_class    = "error";
        } else {

            $username = $_POST['email'];
            $password = $_POST['upass'];

            try {

                $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT userID,username,password FROM users where username = ? ");
                $stmt->execute([$username]);

                $results = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                if (count($results) > 0) {


                    foreach ($results as $row):
                        if (password_verify($password, $row['UserPassword'])) {

                            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = $row['userID'];
                            $loginMessage             = "Login Successfully! Redirecting...";
                            $msg_class                = "success";
                            header("refresh:5; url=dashboard");


                        } else {

                            $loginMessage = "Password and username does not match";
                            $msg_class    = "error";
                        }
                    endforeach;


                } else {


                    $loginMessage = "Invalid username";

                }

            }
            catch (PDOException $e) {

                error_log($e);
            }
        }
    }
}


    ?>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <h1>User Login</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-6 columns large-centered" id="box">
                <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" class="input" >
                    <label>Password </label>
                    <input type="password" name="upass" class="input"  id="password"/><br/>
                    <div class="large-6 columns pull-2"><a href="#">Forgot Password</a></div>
                    <button type="submit" class="button" name="login" disabled="true" id="long">Login</button>
                    <div class="<?php echo $msg_class;?>">
                        <?php
                            echo $loginMessage;
                            ?>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#password').keyup(function(e){

                   $('#long').prop('disabled', false);

                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
```

**db_config.php**

```
<?php


    $servername  = "localhost";
    $username    = "root";
    $password    = "";
    $dbname      = "samedicalspecialists";


    try {

        $conn= new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname",$username,$password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


    } catch (PDOException $e) {


        error_log($e);

    }

?>
```